# How to select all columns except 2 of them from a large table on pyspark sql?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

In joining two tables, I would like to select all columns except 2 of them from a large table with many columns on pyspark sql on databricks.

My pyspark sql:

```
 %sql
 set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;
 select a.*, '?!(b.year|b.month)$).+'
 from MY_TABLE_A as a
 left join 
      MY_TABLE_B as b
 on a.year = b.year and a.month = b.month
```

I followed
[hive:select all column exclude two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54800500/hiveselect-all-column-exclude-two)
[Hive How to select all but one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51227890/hive-how-to-select-all-but-one-column)

but, it does not work for me. All columns are in the results.
I would like to remove the duplicated columns (year and month in the result).

thanks

Comment: Will you be exceeding maximum query length by writing down all columns? You can query system tables to get your columns but It might not be a good idea. It might be lengthy to write them all down but execution will be faster than using some system tables to figure out your columns.

Comment: There are too many columns to type them in the query.

Comment: @user3448011, If the answer helped you to resolve issue.. Could you **`upvote and accept`** the answer to close this thread! :-) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 9):

As of Databricks runtime 9.0, you can use the `* except()` command like this:

```
df = spark.sql("select a.* except(col1, col2, col3) from my_table_a...")
```

or if just using %sql as in your example

```
select a.* except(col1, col2, col3) from my_table_a...
```

Answer (score 4):

`set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none`not supported in **Spark**.

Instead in Spark **`set spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames=true`** to
get same behavior as hive.

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,4)],['id','a','b','c'])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp")
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames=true")

#select all columns except a,b
sql("select `(a|b)?+.+` from tmp").show()
#+---+---+
#| id|  c|
#+---+---+
#|  1|  4|
#+---+---+
```

Answer (score 3):

In pyspark, you can do something like this:

```
df.select([col for col in df.columns if c not in {'col1', 'col2', 'col3'}])
```

where df is the resulting dataframe after the join operation is perfomed.